How to receive a message by Telegram webhook using bot API sendMessage
I use Telegram bot API to create web pages in PHP.
I use webhook to receive chat updates (messages from all users) but I can't receive any update if the message is set by bot API sendMessage.
Is there any reason or it could be my mistake?
// message received by bot using PHP page $message = file_get_contents("php://input");
which should receive a message from bot API, sent by PHP page or Postman
https://api.telegram.org/bot123...:xyz.../sendmessage?chat_id=-123...&text=testText

Is the message you are trying to receive sent by the same bot? Or are you trying to receive message sent by a different bot?

I tried both solution but none worked.

Bot's never receive messages from other bots.

There are two things you might want to achieve:

Your bot receiving updates on messages posted by other bots.
Your bot receiving updates on his own messages.

Bot receiving updates on messages posted by other bots
This approach is not possible, because bots could end up in loops, communicating with each other and wasting Telegram's resources. You can find answer to this in Telegram Bot FAQ.

Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?
Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

Bot receiving updates on his own messages.
I haven't found exact information about this in the official documentation. But from my common sense, when I (my bot) send message to chat, I am rewarded with status code of my request (I know if it failed or went through) and therefore Telegram sending me an update about a message I've sent seems redundant, because I already know, that it happened and I even know, if my request succeeded.

Yes but there is now way to get a specific message content within a chat.
The only way I found out to recreate the history of a chat is to forward the already posted message to an other chat_id. The result is a failure. Through the webhook I can't get the message content scanning all message_id of a known chat. Forwarding each message_id of a chat to get the content of the message itself, I found out that the message_id forwarded (example message_id=29) is not the same of the real message shown into the telegram APP chat (ex https://t.me/chat_name/29) which it is supposed to be the message id

@AdrianoEllero you could store all the messages you send and receive in your database and then have the history by yourself.

for the new messages it's not an issue. Webhook works well.
To recover the pass it's quite tricky.
